# Does PyCharm have a shortcut to Python Interpreter Project Settings?

Tags: python, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts, interpreter

Is there a shortcut for the module manager? Right now I have to go through `Settings` and use the mouse to get to the `module manager`.

[image: Screenshot of Python Interprete settings.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This keyboard shortcut has to be set before it can be used.

1. Go to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Keymap` there search for `Switch Python Interpreter` click on it and select `Edit Shortcuts` add the shortcut you want, as shown in the screenshot.

   [image]
2. If you use the previously configured shortcut in the editor window a menu comes up that lets you choose an interpreter or go to the `Python Interpreter` dialogue.

   [image]

Comment: I wish I could set the shortcut to take me straight to "Interpreter Settings"

Comment: @mblakesley I tried looking for it again and I'm sure no direct action exists for `Settings` `>` `Project` `>` `Python Interpreter`, the closest action is the one in this post (it's basically the same dialogue). You can open the settings with `Ctrl+Alt+S` but that's hardly any closer because you still have to choose an item in the settings list, in this case you get the dialogue directly in the editor.